# combobox selection triggers another combobox selection etc. in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I know this has been asked before, but for some reason it seems like its only working for me to an extent. I set up my XAML like this:

```
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCategoryIndex}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbSourceParam" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceParameters}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSourceParameterIndex}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbTargetParam" ItemsSource="{Binding TargetParameters}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTargetParameterIndex}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Then my ViewModel like this:

```
public class pmCopyParamToParamViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public pmModel model;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryWrapper> Categories { get; private set; }

        public pmCopyParamToParamViewModel(Document doc)
        {
            this.model = new pmModel(doc);
            this.Categories = model.CollectCategories();
            SelectedCategoryIndex = 0;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> _sourceParameters;
        public ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> SourceParameters
        {
            get { return _sourceParameters; }
            set
            {
                if (_sourceParameters == value) return;

                _sourceParameters = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SourceParameters);
                SelectedSourceParameterIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> _targetParameters;
        public ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> TargetParameters
        {
            get { return _targetParameters; }
            set
            {
                if (_targetParameters == value) return;

                _targetParameters = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => TargetParameters);
                SelectedTargetParameterIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        // logic for selected category index
        private int _selectedCategoryIndex;
        public int SelectedCategoryIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedCategoryIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedCategoryIndex == value) return;

                _selectedCategoryIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCategoryIndex);
                SourceParameters = model.CollectParameters(Categories[SelectedCategoryIndex].ID, new string[] { "String", "Double", "Integer" });
            }
        }

        private int _selectedSourceParameterIndex;
        public int SelectedSourceParameterIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedSourceParameterIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedSourceParameterIndex == value) return;

                _selectedSourceParameterIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSourceParameterIndex);
                TargetParameters = model.CollectParameters(Categories[SelectedCategoryIndex].ID, new string[] { SourceParameters[SelectedSourceParameterIndex].StorageType });
            }
        }

        private int _selectedTargetParameterIndex;
        public int SelectedTargetParameterIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedTargetParameterIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedTargetParameterIndex == value) return;

                _selectedTargetParameterIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTargetParameterIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I was expecting to happen is that on ViewModel initilization, it would collect all Categories. I then call `SelectedCategoryIndex` and set it to 0. That in turn should trigger `SourceParameters` to update and set the selected item initially to 0. That in turn would trigger `TargetParameters` to trigger and set the initial `SelectedParameterIndex` to 0.

So far, I am only seeing the Categories and Source Parameters getting set, but the Target Paramters combobox doesn't get set until i manually touch/change selection for the source parameters combobox.

Did I miss something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be the issue?

```
private int _selectedSourceParameterIndex; // Starts off as 0
public int SelectedSourceParameterIndex
{
    set
    {
        // Setting to zero would not change the value, and this will return
        if (_selectedSourceParameterIndex == value) return;

        //... nothing here gets executed ...
        _selectedSourceParameterIndex = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSourceParameterIndex);
        TargetParameters = model.CollectParameters(Categories[SelectedCategoryIndex].ID, new string[] { SourceParameters[SelectedSourceParameterIndex].StorageType });
    }
}
```

I personally prefer binding `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedIndex`. It'll give you the actual object (or null if none is selected) so you don't have to deal with the intricacies of a combobox/list indexing.

Comment: You are right. That's exactly what was happening. I switched my binding to `SelectedItem` and its working just fine now. Thank you!